# Why can't Android release the finished activity from memory after AsyncTask finishes?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, garbage-collection

So I read about memory leaks in Android regarding AsyncTask, and in essence, as far as I understood it's when activity is destroyed for some reason but AsyncTask isn't done, so because AsyncTask has a strong reference to Activity, GC can't collect Activity, i.e. can't release it from memory. My question is, if/when AsyncTask finishes its work and is no longer needed, why can't GC collect that referenced Activity then? Why would that be a problem?

Comment: When you tied up your activity and async task strongly, Asynctask will prevent activity from GC. What you want to do it to avoid using inner keyword for Async task class. Inner classes often outlive their parent class which is what keeps the parent class from GC.

Comment: So it's AsyncTask who is preventing activity from being garbage collected? Why can't it 'nod' when it's finished so GC will be able to collect the Activity?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, inner classes often outlive their parents which is why the parent class become not eligible for GC. As for AsyncTask, if make your async task `inner` and provide it with a **context** of your activity, Android studio will warn that it might cause memory leaks.

> This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur (anonymous android.os.AsyncTask) A static field will leak contexts. Non-static inner classes have an implicit reference to their outer class. If that outer class is, for example, a Fragment or Activity, then this reference means that the long-running handler/loader/task will hold a reference to the activity which prevents it from getting garbage collected. Similarly, direct field references to activities and fragments from these long-running instances can cause leaks. ViewModel classes should never point to Views or non-application Contexts.

Non-static inner class **outlives** its parent. But when you don`t declare it inner that means that you do not have access to parent class members anymore. You can pass in a reference to the Context of your activity but then you run the same risk of a memory leak.

**Solution?**

A possible solution is to provide a weak reference to your context. Another solution is to cancel your async task in onStop() callback of your activity. Moreover, you can confirm the state of your activity using `activityContext.isFinishing()`. If the state equals `true`, simply cancel or return your async task.

A little off topic. Async tasks are a thing of the past, there are other better methods to handle concurrency like RxJava, Kotlin`s coroutines and etc.

Comment: To be honest this is not quite what I was asking. I know the solution. My question was that why can't inner class(in this case) notify parent class that it has finished its work?